# My android Ethereum wallet no longer works. Have I lost them all my ETH coins?

Tags: wallets

I had installed the android application Peerther (Personal Wallet) to manage my ethereum.
It was an investment, I have not really looked at it for several months now.

I just checked right now, and the application just no longer works.
It says error and only asks me to upgrade to another application Copay, which at first look only seems to manage Bitcoins. I have to check that point though. I don't know if there are related.

The error message is:

> Could not update Wallet: Please upgrade Copay to perform this action

I'm wondering if I have lost control over all my ETH coins ?
Has anyone been in the same position as me ? Someone else using an android wallet that went no longer working ?

Do you think there's anywhere I could get my ETH coins back ?

I still have my Ox.... address for my account. It's all.

**EDIT: the application name was Peerther, and not Peether as I thought I was reading on the little screen of my galaxy trend lite phone.
I have emailed the author of the application, but I got no answers yet.**

Comment: Is Peether downloaded from Google Play? By googling this name, it does not seem to have any results

Comment: I have no experience with this implementation. As friendly word of advice, the trick here is to avoid ruining any chance of rescue you have. Ethereum network needs the address and the private key. This is likely still stored in your phone somewhere - we just don't know where to look, because Peether. Suggest you refrain from uninstall, re-install - anything potentially destructive. Possibly a general Android expert can help find something that resembles a keystore. In case it helps, on a PC, it's in a hidden folder, plainly called "keystore" and the keys are in plain text.

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13139/etherli-problem

Comment: i had nstalled an android terminal, I think I will try to search for such a file, thanks.

Comment: @Bigman Indeed the right application name was Peerther, with an "r", and not Peether as I thought I was reading on the screen. I saw mentions of it on the internet. I emailed the author, but no answers yet.

Comment: Possibly a scam app, sorry Stephane

Comment: I cannot comment so I'm writing here. Did you try to scan your address and see if your coins are still here or not ? If you don't know how to do it, give me your 0x address and I'll do this for you.

Comment: Please suggest a way the asker can do this themselves rather than providing tech-support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably got scammed, check following link many users are also reporting this app as scam: 
https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/10175/big-scam-this-wallet

if you have your public address you can check your account balance and transactions at https://etherscan.io/ and if by any chance you have private key you can use myetherwallet.com to transfer to another wallet.