# Etherli Problem

Tags: ether

I bought ethereum about a year ago and transferred it to my ether.li wallet.

Now unfortunately I forgot my password and can't find the sheet I wrote it on.

I tried the "forgot password" Option but I get an error.

I still have all my keys though.
Is there any possibilty to get back my coins?

I contacted the support multiple times but there was no reply year.

Can anybody help?[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

If you've got your private keys then you've always got access to your funds. In crypto currency the private keys are the only thing that count.

You will be able to import the private keys into something like Parity on your computer and have the ability to transfer your funds if needed. MyEtherWallet.com also offer a means to import your private keys to transact with your account.